# Variance Threshold vs Random Forest feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

Can anyone explain what the threshold parameter exactly signify?

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold

thresholder = VarianceThreshold(threshold=.8)
```

What is the difference between threshold=.8 or threshold=.5 ?

Comment: could oyu add more information? What do you expect?

Comment: I wanted to understand what threshold = 0.8  and what does threshold = 0.5 mean?

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing from your question that you don't truly understand what variance is. Lower variance means that there is not much variability in the data. For example, a distribution containing too many similar or same values will have very low variance. In contrast, distributions like `[1,4,56,32,8,9]` will have higher variance because well, its values differ greatly from each other. Obviously, lower variance distributions are not very useful, so you usually choose a threshold to drop such distributions.

I also suggest you read [this](https://community.dataquest.io/t/feature-selection-features-with-low-variance/2418/3) discussion thread from DataQuest.

Answer (score 0):

The threshold parameter is for future selection:

> threshold : float, optional:
>
> Features with a training-set variance lower than this threshold will be removed. The default is to keep all features with non-zero variance, i.e. remove the features that have the same value in all samples

Example

The following dataset has integer features, two of which are the same in every sample. These are removed with the default setting for threshold:

```
X = [[0, 2, 0, 3], [0, 1, 4, 3], [0, 1, 1, 3]]
selector = VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.0)
selector.fit_transform(X)
array([[2, 0],
       [1, 4],
       [1, 1]])
```

try to change this threshold in this example and see what happens